# Windows Update crashes before opening

Tags: windows, windows-update, dism

Windows Server 2016. When I try to open Windows Update (Setting - Update and security), application crashes. In Event Log, I found:

```
Faulting application name: SystemSettings.exe, version: 10.0.14393.82, time stamp: 0x57a55dc6
Faulting module name: Windows.UI.Xaml.dll, version: 10.0.14393.3750, time stamp: 0x5ed5df2d
Exception code: 0xc000027b
Fault offset: 0x00000000006d640b
Faulting process id: 0x2824
Faulting application start time: 0x01d84fef35ce1782
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\ImmersiveControlPanel\SystemSettings.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.Xaml.dll
Report Id: 8fea4980-8d4d-4487-b8a3-15717fa5fd3d
Faulting package full name: windows.immersivecontrolpanel_6.2.0.0_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy
Faulting package-relative application ID: microsoft.windows.immersivecontrolpanel
```

So, I googled for 0xc000027b and found:

```
In elevated command prompt:
dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth
dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth
```

For dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth, I got:

```
Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.14393.3750

Image Version: 10.0.14393.3241

[==========================100.0%==========================] The component store is repairable.
The operation completed successfully.
```

...looks promising. For dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth I got

```
Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.14393.3750

Image Version: 10.0.14393.3241

[==========================100.0%==========================]
Error: 0x800f081f

The source files could not be found.
Use the "Source" option to specify the location of the files that are required to restore the feature. For more information on specifying a source location, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077.

The DISM log file can be found at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

I checked link at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077 and found "Windows Update is the default repair source, but you can configure Group policy to specify one or more network locations that have the files required to restore a Windows feature or repair a corrupted operating system."

And I'm stuck. Why it doesnt check Windows Update? How can I choose another source? Download ISO? Which one?